# Custom Xamarin Forms save button using Syncfusion PDF viewer

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I'm looking to make a button that saves a signed PDF document using the built-in Syncfusion PDF viewer, This is the current code i'm using for the save button but currently it doesn't produce anything, no errors but no output either.

```
        {
            string outputFilePath = "/Files/sdk_gphone_x86_64_arm64/Download";

            try
            {
                using (var pdfStream = await pdfViewerControl.SaveDocumentAsync())
                {
                    pdfStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    using (var outputStream = File.OpenWrite(outputFilePath))
                    {
                        await pdfStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("This isn't working", "This isn't working", "This isn't working");
            }
        }
```

This is the full github project for the app, any help is appreciated.
https://github.com/radnovaxwavez/PDFTest

Comment: Have you traced the code in the debugger to verify it executes?  Does your `catch` trap any exceptions?  Where did you get that file path from?  Is that intended to be the system `Downloads` folder?

Comment: Catch is triggered every time (I added an alert just to test), What should the Downloads folder path look like if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Don’t you think it would be a helpful to include the details of the exception?

Comment: Updated with the alert, as mentioned it's triggered every time...

Comment: The exception object in the catch statement provides useful information about what exactly is causing the exception.  What you are doing in the catch is useless

Comment: I'm aware the catch doesn't currently do much, I just needed it to confirm anything was happening at all. Do you have the default file paths for android, I think that's all this needs.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows